# The following error occurs in the code that I set up and ran in javanetbeans

Tags: java, sql, oop, ide

java/lang. NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mys ql. jdbc. Connection. prepare Statement(String)" because "this con" is null

What should I do to fix that error?  I can't figure out how to fix it.

I want employee_list table to insert data into it.  In that case, when the 'add employee' button is clicked, the data will be stored in SQL. That's what I try to do. Mention the code I made below. Can anyone please help me fix it?

```
package assignment;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.sql.*;

/**
 *
 * @author TOSHIBA
 */
public class Dashboard extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Dashboard
     */
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
   
    public Dashboard() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center form in screen
    }
   
    public Dashboard(String empName,String empDes) {
        initComponents();
        EmpName.setText(empName.toUpperCase());
        EmpDesignation.setText(empDes.toUpperCase());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center form in screen
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   
    void reset(){
        txtFname.setText("");
        txtLname.setText("");
        txtDepartment.setSelectedIndex(0);
        txtDesignation.setSelectedIndex(0);
        txtNumber.setText("");
        txtAddress.setText("");
        txtSalary.setText("");
    }
  
   
    private void jLabelCloseMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        dispose(); // close button
    }                                        

    private void jLabelMinimizeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
        this.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED); // minimize button
    }                                          

    private void btn1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        onClick(btn1);
        onLeaveClick(btn2);
        onLeaveClick(btn3);
        onLeaveClick(btn4);
        onLeaveClick(btn5);
       
        //Switch panels on click
       
        p1.setVisible(true);
        p2.setVisible(false);
        p3.setVisible(false);
        p4.setVisible(false);
        p5.setVisible(false);
       
    }                                

    private void btn2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        onLeaveClick(btn1);
        onClick(btn2);
        onLeaveClick(btn3);
        onLeaveClick(btn4);
        onLeaveClick(btn5);
       
        //Switch panels on click
       
        p1.setVisible(false);
        p2.setVisible(true);
        p3.setVisible(false);
        p4.setVisible(false);
        p5.setVisible(false);
    }                                

    private void btn3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        onLeaveClick(btn1);
        onLeaveClick(btn2);
        onClick(btn3);
        onLeaveClick(btn4);
        onLeaveClick(btn5);
       
        //Switch panels on click
       
        p1.setVisible(false);
        p2.setVisible(false);
        p3.setVisible(true);
        p4.setVisible(false);
        p5.setVisible(false);
    }                                

    private void btn4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        onLeaveClick(btn1);
        onLeaveClick(btn2);
        onLeaveClick(btn3);
        onClick(btn4);
        onLeaveClick(btn5);
       
        //Switch panels on click
       
        p1.setVisible(false);
        p2.setVisible(false);
        p3.setVisible(false);
        p4.setVisible(true);
        p5.setVisible(false);
    }                                

    private void btn5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Login login = null;
        try {
            login = new Login();
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        login.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logout Successful");
       
    }                                

    private void txtDepartmentItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<String> Iterator;
        if(txtDepartment.getSelectedItem().equals("Management")){
            array.add("Head Officer");
            array.add("General Manager");
            array.add("Senior Manager");
            array.add("Junior Manager");
            Iterator = array.iterator();
            while(Iterator.hasNext()){
                txtDesignation.addItem(Iterator.next());
            }
        } else if (txtDepartment.getSelectedItem().equals("HR")){
            array.add("HR Manager");
            array.add("HR Assistent manager");
            array.add("HR Assistent");
            array.add("HR Administrator");
            Iterator = array.iterator();
            while(Iterator.hasNext()){
                txtDesignation.addItem(Iterator.next());
            }
        } else if (txtDepartment.getSelectedItem().equals("Production")){
            array.add("Production Manager");
            array.add("Production Assistent manager");
            array.add("Assistent");
            array.add("Administrator");
            Iterator = array.iterator();
            while(Iterator.hasNext()){
                txtDesignation.addItem(Iterator.next());
            }
        }else if (txtDepartment.getSelectedItem().equals("Sales")){
            array.add("Sales Manager");
            array.add("Sales Assistent manager");
            array.add("Assistent");
            array.add("Administrator");
            Iterator = array.iterator();
            while(Iterator.hasNext()){
                txtDesignation.addItem(Iterator.next());
            }
        }else if (txtDepartment.getSelectedItem().equals("Marketing")){
            array.add("Marketing Manager");
            array.add("Marketing Assistent manager");
            array.add("Assistent");
            array.add("Administrator");
            Iterator = array.iterator();
            while(Iterator.hasNext()){
                txtDesignation.addItem(Iterator.next());
            }
        }else if (txtDepartment.getSelectedItem().equals("IT")){
            array.add("Computer System Manager");
            array.add("Service Desk Analyst");
            array.add("Assistent");
            array.add("Network Administrator");
            Iterator = array.iterator();
            while(Iterator.hasNext()){
                txtDesignation.addItem(Iterator.next());
            }
        }
    }                                              

    private void jPanel23MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        empadd.setVisible(true);
        p1.setVisible(false);
        p2.setVisible(false);
        p3.setVisible(false);
        p4.setVisible(false);
        p5.setVisible(false);
    }                                    

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure to add this record ?","Add record",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (a == 0){
            try{
                String sql = "INSERT INTO `employee_list`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `department`, `designation`, `number`, `address`, `salary`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
               
                pst.setString(1, txtFname.getText());
                pst.setString(2, txtLname.getText());
                pst.setString(3, txtDepartment.getSelectedItem().toString());
                pst.setString(4, txtDesignation.getSelectedItem().toString());
                pst.setString(5, txtNumber.getText());
                pst.setString(6, txtAddress.getText());
                pst.setString(7, txtSalary.getText());
               
                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved successfully");
                reset();
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data not saved successfully in Database");
        }
               
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        empadd.setVisible(false);
        p1.setVisible(false);
        p2.setVisible(true);
        p3.setVisible(false);
        p4.setVisible(false);
        p5.setVisible(false);
       
        reset();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Dashboard.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: You don't obtain a `Connection` from anywhere, which you must before trying to use it. You need also to use those db objects with try-with-resources to ensure they're closed

Comment: Here I have created two forms as login and dashboard.  I have added the login form to the connection.  Should all the connections there be get in to the dashboard form?

Comment: I don't know what that means, but suffice it to say that you must obtain a `Connection` before you attempt to use it. You should only normally have *one* `JFrame` per app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)